# Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE default search locations causing FilePermission issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I have upgraded my spring boot application from 1.2.7.RELEASE to 1.3.0.RELEASE.

ConfigFileApplicationListener in spring boot is loading properties in this fashion

By default properties will be loaded from 'application.properties' and/or 'application.yml' files in the following locations:

```
classpath:
file:./
classpath:config/
file:./config/:
```

My application does not have file or folder read, write access to any where except classpath: and classpath:config/

So, this is causing file permission issues when i start tomcat with security enabled

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" ".\config\application-default.properties" "read")
```

What can i change in spring boot so ConfigFileApplicationListener does not search locations for properties other than classpath:

Answer (score 0):

The default locations are always checked so there's nothing (easy) that you can do to avoid this problem. Can you please [open an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/new) describing your setup, security configuration and the like?